# How to derive gravitational potential from Navier-Stokes equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, potential, integration, navier-stokes

Starting from the Navier-Stokes equation I want to be able to derive the gravitational potential using the Poisson equation but am unsure how to do it in spherical polar coordinates.
This is what I have so far
$$\partial\rho +\nabla\cdot(\rho{\bf v})=0$$
This is satisfied as in my case it is not dependent on time and the system is stationary so ${\bf v}=0$.
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p-\nabla \phi$$
since $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$ we have
$$\nabla \phi=-\frac{1}{\rho} \nabla p$$
I want to integrate the Poisson Equation $\nabla ^2\phi=4\pi G\rho$ in spherical polar coordinates to be able to set it equal to the above equation but I'm really not sure how to go about this so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's not the Navier Stokes equation.  That's Euler's equation.

Comment: What I haven't included on here was my derivation of Euler's equation from the Navier-Stokes equation, but yes you are correct!